# Finding distinct values across multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a function that finds the the number of pno's with the sid (staff id) that have worked on it.
So for example if I wanted to find the sid's corresponding to pno = 1

```
select sid_worked_on(1)

 count 
-------
     2
```

I would have 2 as sid 0 and 1 have worked on it.

This is the joined table from 3 different tables.

```
 pno |  a_sid |  b_sid |  c_sid
-----+--------+--------+--------
   1 |      0 |      0 |      0
   4 |      4 |      4 |      6
   5 |      4 |      4 |      5
   2 |      0 |      0 |      0
   1 |      0 |      1 |      0
   7 |      5 |      4 |      4
   7 |      5 |      5 |      4
   5 |      4 |      4 |      4
   4 |      4 |      5 |      6
   7 |      5 |      4 |      1
   7 |      5 |      5 |      1
   6 |      5 |      4 |      5
```

My only way of thinking how to do it would be to "flatten" the table into one column since there is no need for multiple columns and do distinct sid, but I haven't learnt how to do that yet.

```
pno  |  sid 
-----+--------
   1 |      0 | 
   4 |      4 |
   5 |      4 |
   2 |      0 |    
   1 |      0 |  
   7 |      5 |   
   7 |      5 |
   5 |      4 | 
   4 |      4 |     
   7 |      5 |
   7 |      5 | 
   6 |      5 |   
--where the new table starts
   1 |      0 |
   4 |      4 | 
   5 |      4 | 
   2 |      0 |
   1 |      1 |
   7 |      4 |
  ... 
  ...
```

I also thought to create a table and going through each value, so

```
create table
for each row where pno = 1
       check if a_sid in table
           if not then add a_sid to table
       check if b_sid in table 
           if not then add b_sid to table
       check if c_sid in table
           if not then add c_sid to table
```

Would there be a better way of doing this?

Comment: I cannot understand your description of what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION

```
SELECT pno, a_sid from table
UNION
SELECT pno, b_sid from table
UNION
SELECT pno, c_sid from table
```

Depending on whether you want duplicated entries of the same pno with the same column on the right side, you can use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

You can create a view with this query.